# How to prove that if $P, \mathord{\sim}Q\vdash\bot$, then $P\vdash Q$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to prove that if $P, \mathord{\sim}Q\vdash\bot$, then $P\vdash Q$. Here $\sim$ is negation and $\bot$ means contradiction, i.e. $\bot$ is a proposition that is always false, like $R\wedge\mathord{\sim}R$. In my proof, I used the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem):

*Proof*. If $P, \mathord{\sim}Q\vdash\bot$, then we can write
$\vdash (P\wedge\mathord{\sim}Q)\rightarrow\bot$  and this is equivalent to $\vdash\mathord{\sim}(P\wedge\mathord{\sim}Q)\lor\bot$. So $\vdash(\mathord{\sim}P\lor Q)\lor\bot$ and since $\bot$ is always false, we can write $(\mathord{\sim}P\lor Q)\lor\bot\equiv(\mathord{\sim}P\lor Q)$. Therefore $\vdash\mathord{\sim}P\lor Q$ and so $\vdash P\rightarrow Q$. Therefore $P\vdash Q$ and thus we have proved the claim.

But is this proof correct?

Comment: I think this proof is correct, but it is too complicated. There is a simpler method.

Comment: It depends on the rules available... there is Double Negation Elimination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, ripped out of context, $P \vdash Q$ doesn't have a determinate meaning.

It is like “Jill is before Jack". In what way? On the class list? In who gets to bowl first? In order of birthdays?

Similarly for $P \vdash Q$: this says that $Q$ is provable from $P$, but in what system $S$? This natural deduction system? That axiomatic system? This other resolution calculus?

Think of the likes of $P \vdash Q$ as really short for $P \vdash_S Q$ for some specified proof-system $S$. And until you specify the system $S$, who knows whether what you offer has the makings a proof in *that* system!

Comment: Hmm. You are right. Forgive me because I am not very expert in Metalogic. In fact I meant in mathematical logic. Is mathematical logic a logical system? Or is this word too general and mathematical logic itself has separate logical systems?

Comment: Mathematical logic has multiple logical systems. (There's a nice survey of textbooks where the authors note that of over thirty books which do Fitch-style Natural Deduction -- and that's just one style of one kind of logical system -- *no two textbooks have exactly the same proof system*)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to prove is called Reductio Ad Absurdum and is usually a rule in classical logic, so there shouldn't be much to prove.

Your proof is fine otherwise! (The steps make sense.) But there are some things I´d address though.

1. Most commonly $\mathord\sim P$ is an abbreviation for $P\rightarrow\bot$ for any $P$. Therefore the intermediate steps that have $\lor\bot$ as in $\vdash (\mathord\sim P \lor Q)\lor\bot$ seem redundant.

   You might as well have gone from $\vdash (P\land\mathord\sim Q)\rightarrow\bot$ to $\vdash\mathord\sim P\lor \mathord\sim\mathord\sim Q$ using De Morgan laws directly.
2. In your first step going from $P,\mathord∼Q⊢⊥$ to $⊢(P∧\mathord∼Q)→⊥$ you are using that $P,Q\vdash R$ is the same as $P\land Q\vdash R$ for any $P$, $Q$ and $R$.
3. Your step of going from $\mathord\sim(P\land\mathord\sim Q)$ to $\mathord\sim P\lor Q$ is usually factored into two steps. Namely De Morgan as I did above, and then using that in classical logic $\mathord\sim\mathord\sim P$ is the same as $P$, for every $P$.

   This is the step that has the strength as Reductio Ad Absurdum and pretty much lets you prove this. (Assuming we're in a reasonable system.)

Hope this helps. Cheers!